# Apply Spannable to string in string.xml through parameter

Tags: android, xml, string, spannablestring

I have the following String defined in `string.xml`

```
<string name="photo_heading"><xliff:g name="name">%s</xliff:g> shared a <xliff:g name="permission">%s</xliff:g><xliff:g name="photo">%s</xliff:g> with you.</string>
```

The String accepts 3 string parameters: `name`, `permission`, `photo`

I have two methods that set different style.

```
public Spannable getStyledItalic(String text) {
        Spannable sb = new SpannableString(text);
        sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return sb;
    }
```

and

```
public Spannable getStyledName(String name) {
        Spannable sb = new SpannableString(name);
        sb.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(LPConstants.FONT_SIZE_NAME), 0, name.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, name.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_primary)), 0, name.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return sb;
    }
```

Now I apply these styles to different parameters and return the string but this is not working. Here is what I am doing:

```
public String getHeading(Printrequest printRequest) {
        String name = printRequest.sentbyname;
        String permission;
        String photo;
        if (printRequest.mediaobject.permission != null && !printRequest.mediaobject.permission.equalsIgnoreCase("public")) {
            permission =  printRequest.mediaobject.permission;
        } else {
            permission = "";
        }
        if (printRequest.mediaobject.hyperphoto != null) {
            photo = " " + getStyledItalic(mContext.getString(R.string.hyperphoto));
        } else {
            photo = " " + mContext.getString(R.string.photo);
        }

        String heading = mContext.getString(R.string.photo_heading, getStyledName(name), getStyledItalic(permission), photo);

        return heading;
    }
```

I know we can concatenate `Spannable` with `TextUtils.concat(...)` but my case is different.

**SOLUTION**

Kindly check the solution below. @Krislarson solution is also another way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for down vote but it would have been better if you could come up with a solution.

Comment: use SpannableStringBuilder instead of implicit StringBuilder

Comment: @pskink can you please explain what do you mean as I am not using StringBuilder.

Comment: you are concatenating two strings and it clears the spans

Comment: @pskink yes but how do I concatenate while getting string using getString(R.string....) method? All the struggle is to reuse getStyledItalic(String text) and getStyledName(String name) methods.

Comment: I'd like to know why you are making a `Spannable` string out of XML.  Are you going to show the XML tags in a `TextView`?  Just trying to understand your use case.

Comment: @krislarson Yes, will apply it in a textview

Comment: @krislarson btw what do you mean by XML tags?

Comment: @krislarson I have one textview in which I want to apply this spannable string.

Comment: You have `<xliff:g name="name">` in your string, along with other XML tags.  Did you want that to show in the `TextView`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113745/discussion-between-shahzeb-and-kris-larson).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to do this with a `SpannableStringBuilder`.  Note that the return type has been changed to `CharSequence` to accomodate the `Spannable` string that is built.  You can pass the return value directly to `TextView.setText()`.

```
    public CharSequence getHeading(Printrequest printRequest) {
        String name = printRequest.sentbyname;
        String permission;
        if (printRequest.mediaobject.permission != null && !printRequest.mediaobject.permission.equalsIgnoreCase("public")) {
            permission =  printRequest.mediaobject.permission;
        } else {
            permission = "";
        }

        String photoHeading = mContext.getString(R.string.photo_heading);
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(photoHeading);

        int pos = builder.toString().indexOf("%s");
        builder.replace(pos, pos+2, getStyledName(name));
        pos = builder.toString().indexOf("%s");
        builder.replace(pos, pos+2, getStyledItalic(permission));
        pos = builder.toString().indexOf("%s");
        if (printRequest.mediaobject.hyperphoto != null) {
            builder.replace(pos, pos+2, getStyledItalic(mContext.getString(R.string.hyperphoto)));
            builder.insert(pos, " ");
        } else {
            builder.replace(pos, pos+2, mContext.getString(R.string.photo));
            builder.insert(pos, " ");
        }

        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: I see, so in short we cannot apply Spannable directly through tags in a string?

Comment: @Shahzeb you can use params in string.xml using `TextUtils#expandTemplate` but instead of "%s" you need to pass "^1", "^2", etc. in the template

Comment: You can't do it with `Resource.getString()` because that only works with `String`s as opposed to `CharSequence`s.  You do have `Html.fromHtml()` that takes a string and returns a `Spanned`, but that only parses a very limited set of HTML tags. As a matter of fact, I think it might recognize `<font color="[color]">` as well as `<b>` and `<i>` tags, so you might be able to use `Html.fromHtml()` to get your marked-up text.

Comment: @krislarson FYI see my comment above

Comment: @pskink Ah. Yes indeed.

Comment: @pskink that sounds good. Can you share some example? meanwhile I try it.

Comment: internally it too uses `SpannableStringBuilder` and its `replace()` method as in your answer

Comment: @pskink thanks, TextUtils.expandTemplate() is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I needed `TextUtils.expandTemplate(...)`. Thanks to **@pskink** for pointing out and **@krislarson** for his efforts.

```
<string name="photo_heading"><xliff:g name="name">^1</xliff:g> shared a<xliff:g name="permission">^2</xliff:g> <xliff:g name="photo">^3</xliff:g> with you.</string>
```

and

```
public CharSequence getHeading(Printrequest printRequest) {
        String name = printRequest.sentbyname;
        String permission;
        CharSequence photo;
        if (printRequest.mediaobject.permission != null && !printRequest.mediaobject.permission.equalsIgnoreCase("public")) {
            permission =  " " + printRequest.mediaobject.permission;
        } else {
            permission = "";
        }
        if (printRequest.mediaobject.hyperphoto != null) {
            photo = getStyledItalic(mContext.getString(R.string.hyperphoto));
        } else {
            photo = mContext.getString(R.string.photo);
        }

        return TextUtils.expandTemplate(mContext.getString(R.string.photo_heading), getStyledName(mContext, name), getStyledItalic(permission), photo);
    }
```

Comment: it will not work, you cannot do: `" " + getStyledItalic(mContext.getString(R.string.hyperphoto));` as your italic span will be cleared

Comment: @pskink would changing to CharSequence help? Actually I don't have any case which enters this check so it was working fine till now.

Comment: i dont think so, but try it

Comment: You add the space in either case; couldn't you just put that in the string? `...name="permission">^2</xliff:g> <xliff:g name="photo"...` Then you could get rid of that concatenation, which is a string operation.

Comment: @krislarson I could but actually permission is the issue, if its "public" I don't have to show anything else show permission. So if its public, double space will appear.

Comment: You could have another string like: `<string name="photo_heading_public"><xliff:g name="name">^1</xliff:g> shared a <xliff:g name="photo">^2</xliff:g> with you.</string>`  and just use that when permission is blank.

Comment: @krislarson did it with a minor change. moved space in permission and removed the one before it because I was applying style to it after concatenation.